# Find if GPS provider failed to get location in android

Tags: android

How can I find out that the GPS provider has failed to get location in android?
Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589811/gps-timeout-in-android

Comment: If you don't get an answer for your question try to modify your question and clarify the problem... share some code with us with the error or try to be more specific. I think you got some nice answers and you have to live with them

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain a bit more  your question? Basically if the provider is not null, the position will give you is aproximated in the case of NETWORK_PROVIDER or more precise in case GPS_PROVIDER.